# Laravel 4 model not found inside a namespace

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

"Class `ModelName` not found", "`Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR)`" is showing while using `ModelName::find(1)` in the controller which have a namespace of `Controllers\admin` and model is without any namespace. on the top of file, i applied `use ModelName;`. after following many guides, i applied `php composer dump-autoload` and `composer du`.
still shows model not found. what is the reason and how to use `ModelName` using Eloquont ?

Comment: Which file did you add the `use ModelName;` statement to? Does it work if you access the model using the global namespace?  e.g. `\ModelName::find(1)`

Comment: I use ModelName::find(1); , @patricus and now i tried \ModelName and still shows the same. should i use use \ModelName instead of use ModelName ?

Comment: Can you show your model and controller code?

Comment: Thank you @patricus for your kind help..
I fixed the mess. that was because of the directory structure. I made the model via Jeffrey Way's generator { [Jeffrey Way's Laravel Generators in github](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators) } and the directory structure is different from native laravel and i forget to check dir structure. Once again thank you for trying to help me.